# How can I hide a google places api key that needs to be in the index.html of a react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-places-api

I have a mern stack with a payment page I want to implement google places api for an address auto complete feature in the form. I have the form figured out but I need to add this script tag in the html.

```
<script>
  (g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})({
    key: "YOUR_API_KEY_HERE",
    v: "weekly",
    // Use the 'v' parameter to indicate the version to use (weekly, beta, alpha, etc.).
    // Add other bootstrap parameters as needed, using camel case.
  });
</script>
```

How am I supposed to access a process.env.API_KEY variable from within the index.html at the public part of the react app?

Comment: you can't hide the API key, even if you read it from the env variable. In the final build, the actual API key will be exposed.

Comment: Thats what i was thinking. so people just expose it? seems sketchy

Comment: API keys are meant to live on the server only. Your frontend app make API calls to your server, your server use whatever API keys stored on the server to call for external services, process the response and then respond to your frontend app.

Comment: Refer to Google's [API best practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices) guide. In summary restrict the keys to specific apis, add additional validations like referrer protections. Some keys are ok to be exposed in script files as mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use the .env file for storing the important and secret keys for the file.

Also one more trick is available that you can store the encrypted key in the backend. When you need it call the API for it. The server will return the encrypted data and after that you can decrypt that key from your side by performing some actions and utilize the key wherever you needed.

If you are using firebase in your project than you can store the secrets in Remote configs. So you can also change it whenever you needed.